# Basic XSS veracode vulnerabilty in Angular application for href

Tags: javascript, angular, href, xss, veracode

While running the vera code static scan I am getting basic XSS vulnerability flaw on setting href to the response data. I am using angular version 5

[href]="responseData.url"

This response data I a getting from HTTP response from the server.
Need help in resolving this vulnerability.

As per Angular documentation, it will automatically sanitize all the URLs.
Still, I have tried creating a pipe and inside that pipe, I am sanitizing the URL manually using sanitize() of angular DOMSanitizer.

That doesn't work as well even it increases the vulnerability of vera code.

[href]="responseData.url" => this is inside an anchor tag

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @andreasnico, I want to remove this vera code vulnerability from my Angular application.

Comment: Is it a real vulnerability or a false positive?

Comment: yes as per vera code it is real vulnerability, a security flaw

Comment: @VarunKumar — Eh? "as per vera code"? That doesn't make sense. You can't tell if something is a false positive or not by simply trusting that the software which reported it never makes false positives!

Answer (score 0):

Just checked with the Veracode team, It seems to be a false positive by Veracode static scan. Soon Veracode will fix this.

https://community.veracode.com/s/feed/0D52T00004mhd2W